# django-cms - the pages are visible only to the administrator

Tags: django, django-cms

The pages are visible only to the administrator. After creating the page, I can only see it if I have administrator rights. If I go to `127.0.0.1:8000` from another browser, I will only see the menu.
I installed `django-cms` using `djangocms-installer`:

```
$ python3 -m venv env
$ source env/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install djangocms-installer
(env) $ mkdir myproject && cd myproject
(env) $ djangocms -f -p . my_demo
(env) $ python manage.py runserver
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share code, otherwise noone can help you. Maybe you have only admin site.

Comment: Sounds to me like the pages aren't published.